# How to search and replace with in 2d array in android

Tags: android, search, multidimensional-array, replace, expert-system

I have sqlite db with 4 columns. i.e. id , rule body, cons and bool. i can insert data to it and retrieve using a cursor and store in 2d array. example row can be like

```
id     rule body                 cons              bool
1      jogging(?X)               athelete(?x)      0
2      athelete(?X)              runsfast(?x)      0
3      athelete(?X),runsfast(?x) champion(?x)      0
```

same is the structure of array without columns heading. now what i want to do it that a user has to give input in the following format

```
jogging(alan)
```

it has to replace the ?x in the 2darray and enter alan in the ?x place.

```
1      jogging(alan)                  athelete(alan)      0
2      athelete(alan)                 runsfast(alan)      0
3      athelete(alan),runsfast(alan)  champion(alan)      0
```

IF jogging(alan) is found copy the cons of jogging(alan) to newarray[].

```
newarray[athelete(alan)]
```

newarray[] now carry athlete(alan). now the newarray[] has been updated so search again for athlete(alan) if found save runsfast(alan) into newarray[]. again updated and we have athelete(alan),runsfast(alan) in newarray[].

```
newarray[athelete(alan),runfast(alan)]
```

now search for athelete(alan),runsfast(alan) and add champion(alan) to newarray[] repeat again and this time no match found so quit.

```
newarray[athelete(alan),runfast(alan),runfast(alan)]
```

any ideas please

Comment: Can you do that search in your database ?

Comment: @AxelH i will prefer to use arrays but any idea is most welcome.

Comment: If you only need the result of your search, let sqlite do the work, a WHERE rule_body LIKE ... would be easier, but with some limits.
If not, you just need a loop and check the correct columns for a specific content, using a regex my do the trick. To simple solution.

Comment: thank you for your comments. it might be useful for me.

Comment: but its not a query which can be done by using LIKE. but regex might play a part

Comment: Why a LIKE could not do the trick ? I have done it for a filter. If you can explain a bit better the condition I could find something.

Comment: @AxelH for example i have a stored at array[0][2] the values person(?X), then i am using a textbox to enter person(alan) which means that ?x is a variable which is storing a value alan. now i want to search in array where ?x is appearing between a text. once found replace ?x with alan. this is the first part i want to do. once the match is found and replace the array value adjacent to array[0][3] has to be stored in one dimensional array. as the search will be recursive on one dimensional array till all 2d array is traversed and no value can be further entered into one d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to use the split using a character in ur case its ( so it will split the
joggin(?X) into jogging and ?x) u can strip it ) using replace method. similarly do it with the jogging(alan) so it will be joggin and alan)
add them to arraylist or any storing structure which u can use with ease. in case of array u can search if

```
rule[x] Matches fact[x] 
copy fact[x+1] into rule[x+1]
```

so in case it find that jogging in one array equal jogging in other array, copy the next item to other array replacing ?x.

i guess u r working on rule based horn-clauses thats why u r using that format?

Answer (score 0):

Use HashMap to store a single row elements with unique keys and store the maps in a arraylist. You can retrieve each map in a loop and get the value for the key.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach than keeping reference of your sqlite data in an array, would be to use cursor loader and work with cursor at position, rater then working with 2d arrays. Cursors are transient, can be closed and discarded. Easier to manipulate using swapping cursor in adapter... and so on. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I edit the complet answer since you update the question to set a correct example.

Using SQLite to do it, I would use something like this : (not tested)

```
SELECT id, replace( rule body, '?X', alan ) AS 'rule_body', replace( cons, '?X', alan ) AS 'cons', bool 
     FROM table 
     WHERE rule_body LIKE athelete(alan) 
         OR cons LIKE athelete(alan);
```

This should return the correct row corresponding to the name you want. You need to set the NAME and not the text from the input (extract the name)

If you really want to work with your array, you need to loop the array and check the second and thrird column (I guess on both field).

```
String[][] array = new String[2][4]; //The result array
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
String name = ""; //extract the name from the form input.
for(String[] tmp : array){
   if(isValid(tmp, name)){ //a method to check the field 1 and 2 of tmp with name
      result.add(tmp[2]) //the cons row
   }
}
```

You just have to create **isValid(String[] row, String name)** to check if the name is found in the correct fields. Using a regex to check if you found **'(' + name + ')'** will do the trick.

Comment: Actually i have a database where the format is saved in the one u wrote above like id, rule body etc. i get these into a 2d array. now a user may enter input in the form of jogging(alan) , in that case i have to extract alan and replace ?x in the array, and the athelete(alan) will be stored in another array(this array if is updated will trigger another search) like if i get the athelte(alan) and i have athlete(alan) in the 2darray with a consequence of runfast(alan) then runfast(alan) will be stored in a array again till no update is found. it is kind of rule based system.

Comment: Edit your question to explain, show the exact structure of your DB, the kind of search (what is the String you will use), the result expected.
The comment section is not useful for this. And try to be readable...

Comment: please have a look now @Axelh